# Having Bad access while using SCRecorder

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I am facing a issue while using `SCRecorder` in iOS. While setting the image in `SCSwipeableFilterView`, I am getting a "bad access" error.

```
self.filterSwitcherView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
self.filterSwitcherView.filters = @[
                                    [SCFilter emptyFilter],
                                    [SCFilter filterWithCIFilterName:@"CIPhotoEffectNoir"],
                                    [SCFilter filterWithCIFilterName:@"CIPhotoEffectChrome"],
                                    [SCFilter filterWithCIFilterName:@"CIPhotoEffectInstant"],
                                    [SCFilter filterWithCIFilterName:@"CIPhotoEffectTonal"],
                                    [SCFilter    filterWithCIFilterName:@"CIPhotoEffectFade"]
                                    ];

[self.filterSwitcherView setSelectedFilter:[SCFilter emptyFilter]
[self.filterSwitcherView setImageByUIImage:self.imageForPhoto];
```

In the last line of this code having the bad access issue. It is working when I commented out the last line of code.
    Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the problem appears on iOS prior to **9.0**.